# DataTables undefined 'length' property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using DataTables in my MVC project, but when i returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error.

My js code:

```
$('.datatable-responsive-column-controlled').DataTable({
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax: {
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("List", "Prices"))",
        type: "POST"
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "Id" },
        { "data": "Name" },
        { "data": "Price" },
    ],
    ordering: false,
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column'
        }
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets: 0
        },
        {
            width: "100px",
            targets: [3]
        },
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [3]
        }
    ]
});
```

And this is my json result:

```
{"ExtraData":null,"Data":[{"Name":"Apple","Price":"TRY 15.50","Id":1}],"Errors":null,"Total":1,"iTotalRecords":1,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1}
```

PS: I've searched existing questions, but nothing solved my problem. Because of that I asked a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from documentation (see reference section), `DataTable` expects JSON response from `JsonResult` action method called by AJAX containing one of these structures:

**1) Simple array of data**

```
// JSON
[{ "Name":"Apple",
   "Price":"TRY 15.50",
   "Id":1 }]

// DataTable
$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    // column definition
});
```

**2) Object with `data` property**

```
// JSON
"data": [{ "Name":"Apple",
          "Price":"TRY 15.50",
          "Id":1 }]

// DataTable
$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
        dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    // column definition
});
```

Since `data` property in passed JSON object named as `Data` (note that the capital letter makes difference because JS has case-sensitive rule), there you should use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to set data property name:

```
$('.datatable-responsive-column-controlled').DataTable({
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax: {
        url: "@Url.Action("List", "Prices")",
        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: "Data" // add this line
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "Id" },
        { "data": "Name" },
        { "data": "Price" },
    ],

    // other stuff
});
```

References:

[DataTables Manual - AJAX Data array location](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

[DataTables: Common JS Console Errors](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)